# How to make first letter after hypen in string to be capital

Tags: php, jquery

If I have string like `hybert-metal` then I need the output to be `Hybert-Metal`

I tried these scripts:

```
<?php 
    $form['surname']->render(array('onChange'=>"javascript:this.value = this.value.toLowerCase()", 'onBlur'=>"javascript:this.value=this.value.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){ return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase()})"));
?>
```

```html
<input type="text" name="surname" onchange="javascript: this.value = this.value.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){ return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toUpperCase() })" onblur="javascript: this.value = this.value.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){ return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase() })" id="surname">
```

On trying script this makes `Hybert` but make string `metal` stays as its is. The output after my script is `Hybert-metal` but I need `Hybert-Metal`.

The problem is that I cannot make string first text capital. Any suggestion is most welcome.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for JS or PHP code here as you can do this in CSS alone using `text-transform: capitalize`:

```css
span {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<span>hybert-metal</span>
```

> i need to type on textbox so onchange event would fire css trick don"t works

Yes it does, as it works for `input` elements too:

```css
.capitalise {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="capitalise" value="hybert-metal" />
```

Comment: i need to type on textbox so onchange event would fire css trick don"t works

Comment: Doesn't work on my firefox (aurora). As hybert-metal counts as one word, the "metal" one doesn't uppercased

Comment: @Chay22 In that case PHP would be your best option. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: Assuming you mean does it place a capital after a `'`, then yes. You can try it in the examples I created above.

Comment: jsffidle : http://jsfiddle.net/B3xA4/156/ thats not working please help

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you can do it with javascript regexp and replace methods:

```
function capitalizeStrings(input) {

  if (typeof(input) == 'string') {
    var result = input.replace(input.substr(0,1), input.substr(0,1).toUpperCase());
    var index = result.match(new RegExp("-")).index;    
    result = result.replace(result.substr(index+1,1), result.substr(index+1,1).toUpperCase());

    return result;
  }

}
console.log(capitalizeStrings("hybert-metal")); // The output will be Hybert-Metal
```

And you can invoke this function from php (based on your example) as:

```
<?php 
$form['surname']->render(array('onChange'=>"capitalizeStrings(this.value)"));
?>
```

Comment: hi Simon i have checked console.log print same thing but , Im not getting result in textbox updated

Comment: The same thing as the original? It shouldn't.

Comment: What do you mean? You have accepted the response, this means it's working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `explode`, `implode` and `array_map` functions to do what you want.

```
$string = 'hybert-metal';
$newString = implode('-', array_map(function ($value) {
    return ucfirst($value);
}, explode('-', $string)));

echo $newString;
```

What I am doing here:

- explode the string on `-`
- ucfirst each value of the resulting array
- implode the resulting array with `-`

Another option could be to use `str_replace` and `ucwords`

```
$newString = str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $string)));
```

A similiar method (found in the PHP manual)

```
function ucwords_delimited($string) {
    $string =ucwords(strtolower($string));

    foreach (array('-', '\'') as $delimiter) {
        if (strpos($string, $delimiter) !== false) {
            $string = implode($delimiter, array_map('ucfirst', explode($delimiter, $string)));
        }
    }
    return $string;
}
```

#### Update

I took a closer look at the `ucwords` function. By reading the manual I learned that this function has a second (optional) parameter that let's you choose the delimiter. This makes it alot easier for us and so we can leave out `str_replace`.

```
// Make each word start with a capital
ucwords('something-devided', '-');
```

*Note* This is supported in PHP >= 5.4.32, 5.5.16

#### Reference

- [explode() - manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
- [implode() - manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)
- [ucfirst() - manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php)
- [array_map() - manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)
- [str_replace() - manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)
- [ucwords() - manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php)